# Updating a dataset changes with data adapter does not seem to work properly

Tags: c#, data-binding

I wanted to update my dataset changes to my database, so I used this sort of code:

```
SqlCommandBuilder mySqlCommandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(sqladap);
sqladap.Update(ds, TableName);
```

While it works properly I have used this code for another dataset in my project but the second one does not work. I traced this code and saw the rows of the dataset. It contains both last fetched rows and new rows but the SQLDataAdapter updates any data and also it does not throw an error.

here is the full code:

```
public static SqlDataAdapter AdapterStoredProcedure(string sp_Name, object obj)
{
        ClsEventLogs EventLogs = new ClsEventLogs();
        try
        {
            SqlConnection connection = SQLDBConnection();

            SqlDataAdapter sqladap = new SqlDataAdapter(sp_Name, connection);
            sqladap.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            if (obj != null)
            {
                Type t = obj.GetType();
                string str = string.Empty;
                System.Reflection.FieldInfo[] fields = t.GetFields();
                foreach (System.Reflection.FieldInfo field in fields)
                {
                    sqladap.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(field.Name, SqlDbType.VarChar, 200));
                    sqladap.SelectCommand.Parameters[field.Name].Value = field.GetValue(obj).ToString();
                }
            }                
            return sqladap;
        }
        catch(Exception er)
        {
            EventLogs.Eventlog("clsDataStore : ExecuteStoredProcedure", er.Message, ClsEventLogs.EventType.etCriticalError, false);
            return null;
        }            
    }

// Creating Adapter

SqlDataAdapter dAdap = null;
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
dAdap = clsDataStore.AdapterStoredProcedure("sp_SelectTbl_Client", null);            
dAdap.Fill(ds, "tbl_client");

//here is where i'm Updating the dataset
SqlCommandBuilder mySqlCommandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(sqladap);
sqladap.Update(ds, TableName);
```

Comment: @Kobe. OK. I edited the post and posted the full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to look (Debugger) at the generated SQL Update/Insert statements. Most likely they are flawed or even empty.

The CommandBuilder is extremely limited, it only deals with very simple SELECT a, b FROM table statements.

You will probably find that the SP that doesn't work contains a JOIN, computed column or something like that.

Best course: provide your own Update statements or SPs

Comment: the new SP is just like  the other one i used with the CommandBuilder early in my project and that works fine. no join no computed column an so on. i used SQL_Server profiler and saw any update script when running that update.

Answer (score 0):

To ask the dumb question: did you tell your adapter to commit the changes after calling the `Update` method?

**EDIT:** OK, now that you've posted your code, I have to ask another dumb question: what are you looking at to determine if the update worked? Are you connecting to a remote database right now, or a test database in the project? If it's the latter, then if you are rebuilding each time (something I'm in the habit of doing) then your working copy of the database (in the `\bin` directory) gets blown away and replaced with a fresh copy from wherever it's referenced from in the project. That assumes, of course, that you're using an embedded DB (like MSSQLCE).

Comment: What do you mean? the SQLDataAdapter in .net does not have commit method and i think it assumed that the update method commits the changes by itself.

Comment: You are correct. I was thinking you might have been using a transaction in your code, but your updated question shows that to be untrue.

Comment: My database is in SQL_SERVER on the local machine and is not  the test database.